# How to add data to $scope in angular that is accessed in a http-response?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with a facebook tab. It's an iframe posts will recieve certain in the http-response only if the page is embedded in an iframe. This means that I can't use $http as I normally do. I try to figure out how to supply this data to angular.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
        <?php 
            if($signed_request['page']['liked'] == 1){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">$scope.liking = true</script>';
            }else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">$scope.liking = false</script>';
            }
?>
```

I have considered adding some sort of html-field, like an input type="hidden" with a ng-model attatched to it, but it feels kind of hacky. Does angular have any suggested approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Got the same problem. Did you find any answer?